# Chevrolet Cruze running out of Coolant

Tags: chevrolet, coolant, cruze

Can my Chevy Cruze 2011 ran out of Coolant liquid after 6 years of use ??. Some people say that coolant never decreases, then why is sold in regular car stores?. Can be possible or do I need to make a car inspection due to an engine problem. Note: Living in Canada under extreme cold winters.
Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "ran out", do you mean the system was completely empty? Or just the reservoir/expansion tank was empty? Are you seeing wet spots under the car? Is there any physical evidence of a leak?

Comment: @CharlieRB : reservoir/expansion tank was empty, and I refilled due to heating not working, immediately after refill the heating started working normally

Comment: @CharlieRB : My fear is some people say leak of coolant could lead to an engine damage

Comment: I have a 2014 eco. This past summer I was losing coolant often. Could not see any wetness under car. I had to add 3 gallons over a 2 month span. Dealership came n towed it 2 hrs away. Told me they couldnt find no leak, but replaced the water pump? Got my car back in sept. Have had to fill up twice again? Calling dealership again!! Hope you get yours sorted out!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides outright leaks, yes, a car can lose some coolant over time. This typically happens through evaporation from the expansion tank. Sounds like your coolant was simply low, but not empty.

The 2011 Chevy Cruze cooling system holds approximately 5.8 quarts total. If it were empty you would have had to add about a gallon and a half.

Engine damage would have only happened if the coolant was low enough to cause overheating, which you would know because the temperature gauge would have climbed to the "red" and the warning lights would turn on. If none of that happened, you should be alright.

Comment: I refilled to the line mark with only a quarter gallon, and then with the time it lowered, that means I need to fill a little more to the line mark again?

Comment: Yes. It likely worked some air out of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough rep to comment, so check this bulletin https://www-odi.nhtsa.dot.gov/acms/cs/jaxrs/download/doc/UCM507379/SB-10057265-3557.pdf and get back to us with more information about the engine, trim, and equipment for a more accurate response.

While it is correct that coolant is not usually "consumed" in operation, it definitely can leak out from a number of places. Especially in very hot or cold environments. Cold can weaken and damage seals that keep coolant in.

Check that bulletin to see if your vehicle is covered, otherwise we can investigate with more information about the problem. You will also want to refill the coolant to the recommended level in the meantime.

Comment: I already refilled

Answer (score 0):

You might have a crack in your coolant reservoir. I just replaced mine and my car is a 2014 Chevy cruze